# page refresh multiple times on location.href

Tags: javascript

I have a javascript program that redirects to a different page if the device is mobile but once it redirects it keeps on refreshing the page over and over again. What is the cause of this did I miss anything in the code. How can I make it redirect but stop the refresh? Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

```js
var isMobile = /iPhone|iPad|iPod|Android/i.test(navigator.userAgent);
if (isMobile) {
  console.log("mobile")
  document.location.href = 'index2.html'
} else {
  console.log("desktop")
}
```

Comment: Well if `isMobile` is true, it's gonna keep calling `document.location.href = 'index.html'`. You should check the current href to see if it needs to be redirected

Comment: do you have this same script running on index.html ?

Comment: is your code in the same page it's being redirected to? If yes, well of course it's gonna get executed again and again as long as that if passes true

Comment: no, the page is not being redirected to the same origin @G-Man

Comment: @seriously that is not what I said. What I am saying is that if index.html references the script that has the code that is shown above, you are done and will be stuck in a loop while on mobile

Comment: @G-Man no index.html is a different script

Comment: show us your `index2.html` as well?

Answer (score 0):

The only way this will be happening is if `index2.html`, or whatever page you are re-directing to, runs this script as well.
For example:

```
  document.location.href = 'https://www.facebook.com'
```

Will not refresh multiple times after redirecting to Facebook as Facebook.
Whereas if you redirect to the same page, `isMobile` will also be true, so it will always refresh